# Why has oplog size in mongodb been reset?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I am working with a replica set on MongoDB. Therefore I have increased the oplog size, since it fit the use case. However, I have noticed after a couple of months that it has been reset at some point of time. Does anyone know when this can happen?

Regards and thanks in advance

tryed stopping mongodb, removing instance from replica set, restarting vm

Comment: Did you restart or upgrade the database?

Comment: It has been restarted, but I have restarted it again to check if this was the cause, but apparently it was not. The database has not been updated.